# How do I maintain consistency between third-party API and my own database?

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, transactions

I am working with REST API and have the following scenario for processing request to make a payment:

1. A client sends the request (payment information) to my own API.
2. My API calls third-party REST API, passes it payment information, and receives a payment ID from it. If third-party API call fails for any reason, the error is returned to the client immediately.
3. My API stores the resulting payment ID from step 2 and some extra info to its own database.

I want the data to be consistent between third-party API and my own database. However, if for some reason the database is not accessible on step 3, I will end up with inconsistent data — the payment will exist in third-party API, but not in my own API's database.

What's the best way of handling this consistency issue?

Comment: There are multiple mechanisms to do that: store the transaction data to disk and when the db is available then insert the data, cancel on the third party the payment, hold it on memory until the db gets up, etc etc, so basically this is a primarily opinion based question... FYI, I would store the data on a disk cache and check each X interval if the DB has become available and then insert all the missing data.

Comment: @Gusman I disagree with the notion that this is a trivial problem (*there are multiple mechanisms* etc.).  If you write to disk and a MSSQL database, you still need MSDTC to coordinate the transaction.  However, writing to disk could fail as well.  If you store in memory, the process could fail *after* the REST call is complete.

Comment: I did not say it's trivial, that task can be extremely complex if you need a 0 failure tolerance, what I meant is that there are multiple ways to achieve the result, so it's opinion based, not sure if it wasn't clear :).

Answer (score -1):

@Gusman talks about how to allow step 2 if step 3 cannot be completed.

[TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows you to do steps 2 and 3 in the same transaction, i.e. step 2 is cancelled if step 3 cannot be completed.

Comment: `TransactionScope` will **not** work to automatically rollback step 2.  Step 2 is an out or process call.

Comment: @Davin Do you have any references for your comment? It is my understanding that TransactionScope is designed for distributed transactions, so step 2 is only committed on `scope.Complete()`. See, for example, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope#hDistributedTransSys

Comment: HTTP is stateless. A rest call will not be automatically rolled back unless you write specific MSDTC code. Even then the 3rd party would have to provide a mechanism to rollback, since you are not in control of that code.

Comment: Can you explain how `step 2 is cancelled`?

Comment: It boils down to, “Does the OP’s third party API support MSDTC?” I assumed it would.

Comment: If they are using HTTP, then certainly not.

Comment: MSDTC uses port ranges that are not usually supported for a third party.  And would certainly not usually be open for a REST API.